# Creating a gridview with multiple clickable items (categories)

Tags: flutter, gridview

I want to make a multi-selectable gridview with twelve categories. I'm having trouble creating the clickable and unclickable part of it. In addition, how can I make it so that the user can choose more than one category? As you can see in the code below, I have about twelve categories in the grid that I want a user to click based of their interests, which is why a multi-select is needed.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: const Text('Interests'),
    ),
    resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
    body: GridView.count(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
      childAspectRatio: (6 / 1),
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      // Create a grid with 1 columns.
      crossAxisCount: 1,
      children: <Widget> [
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: const Text('Food & Drinks'),
          color: Colors.teal[100],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
          child: const Text('Sport'),
          color: Colors.teal[200],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: const Text('Fitness'),
          color: Colors.teal[300],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: const Text('Animals'),
          color: Colors.teal[100],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
          child: const Text('Parent hang'),
          color: Colors.teal[200],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: const Text('Film'),
          color: Colors.teal[300],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: const Text('Explore'),
          color: Colors.teal[100],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
          child: const Text('Nature'),
          color: Colors.teal[200],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: const Text('Gaming'),
          color: Colors.teal[300],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: const Text('Music'),
          color: Colors.teal[100],
        ),
        Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
          child: const Text('Art'),
          color: Colors.teal[200],
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          child: Center( 
            child: Text('Culture events', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)
          ),
        ]
      )
    ); 
  }    
}
```

Comment: Hi! I’ve made a few changes to your post, so it’d be useful if you could review them. Notably, the formatting was inconsistent in your code, so I adjusted the indentation so everything lined up. As part of that, I identified what I believe to have been two extraneous parentheses; since I assume that doesn’t relate to the problem you’re dealing with, I took the liberty of removing it. I also removed the back ticks since you were using indentation. Finally, I made some adjustments for readability.

Answer (score 0):

You need to surround each `Container` with an `Inkwell` (if you want a ripple effect on click) or a `GestureDetector` (if you just want a simple tap).

After that, you have to initialise a structure that keeps track of whether the item is clicked or not. For example, an array of boolean values which has the corresponding index as `true` if the corresponding item is clicked.

In the `onTap()` method of your surrounding `Inkwell`/`GD`, set the value in the structure you made above. Also, add an indication about the selection, like invert colors of the text and background, or change the background color if the item is selected vs not selected.

Comment: Do you mean like this?    (https://gyazo.com/f9a1262727f9391d79813f337d000825)

Comment: Yup, Modify your `onTap()` as I've said. it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this plugin from Flutter Packages:

[drag_select_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/drag_select_grid_view)